# Android localization does not work in the application, but the background processes take the strings of the desired locale

Tags: java, android, xml, localization

Android localization does not work in the application, but the background processes take the strings of the desired locale (AlarmManager, provided if the application is closed by the user).

And the caption of the icons on the homescreen also uses the correct locale.

If the application is launched during an alarm, the default English strings are used.

Folder names:

```
values values-ru (tried values-ru-rRU)
```

if I put Russian strings in the values-port application uses them (ie, obviously, it’s not a matter of strings).

I assumed that the activity does not correctly detect the language.
but

```
String l = Locale.getDefault ().GetLanguage();
returns "ru"
```

I did exactly the same thing that I always just copied the values ​​folder with adding the necessary locale (in a particular case, ru)

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
 targetSdkVersion 27
```

Comment: In the translation editor did you see Default value and the other language? (ru)

Comment: All of them. Without any warnings. I created few strings for nav bar. And it works correctly. so I thought maybe the android studio does not see changes. I renamed key name for all of my strings. restarted the studio with deleting the cache. but nothing has changed. The correct strings only in background processes , application name and now in bottom navigation bar